# Order of elements in the symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

What are the elements of order $2$ of the symmetric group $S_n$?

I've tried listing some of the sets for small $n$ to get a better understanding but I'm really not sure:

$S_1$ has only one element and that's order $1$.
$S_2$ has elements $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ ; the first of these is order $1$ and the second is order $2$.

I don't know how to proceed though.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says any permutation is the product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: why are the elements of $S_2$ weird matrices?

Comment: And the theorem that says that disjoint cycles commute?

Comment: Oh the top row has the elements from $1$ to $n$ and the bottom row tells us where each one is going?

Comment: Yep Jorge sorry for the confusion:) I know those theorems but not sure how to apply them

Comment: I think most of my friends prefer understanding permutations through cycle representation for most things. I think once you get comfortable with that way of viewing things this problem will become easy for you.

Comment: From those theorems, it should be clear that a product of disjoint $2$-cycles has order $2$.  Can you prove those are the only elements of order $2$?

Comment: I think I got it - so only those subsets of order $2$ satisfy the criteria - e.g.. for $S_3$ we have $(1 2), (1 3)$ and $(2 3)$ being the only such elements of order $2$? It's easy to prove these are of order $2$, I just need to show the other elements are not order $2$. The one element members clearly have order $1$ ; if a subset has $n$ elements then order = n but I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: @Jorge: That’s the “two-line notation”, where the permutation takes the elements of the top line to the corresponding bottom line.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Hint: any permutation is a a product of disjoint cycles. If $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_k$ are disjoint cycles, the order of $\sigma= \sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_k$ is the least common multiple of the orders of the $\sigma_i$. So what can you say about the orders of the $\sigma_i$ if the order of $\sigma$ is $2$?

Answer (score 2):

The elements of $S_n$ of order $2$ are those permutations $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(\varphi(x)) = x$ for all $x$.

One way for this to happen is to have $\varphi(x) = x$, however if we have $\varphi(x) = y$ with $y\neq x$ then we must have $\varphi(y)=x$.

What this means is that our function $\varphi$ will split the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ into two different numbers. We first have the set $F$ of numbers that are fixed by $\varphi$. We also have the set of numbers $M$ that are moved by $\varphi$, and these numbers get split into pairs of numbers, such that for each pair $\{a,b\}$ we have $\varphi(a)=b$ and $\varphi(b)=a$.

The problem is that this description is a bit confusing haha, and especially when looking at your way of representing permutations it can be a bit confusing.

However if you look at the "disjoint cycle representation" you just need all the cycles to have size $2$.

Also, permutations of order $2$ are called involutions, so perhaps you can find more stuff by searching that.